# Empty page when hiding tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I've got a number of tablixes and they hide/show expressions.
If we run the report for a particular dataset, the first tablix is shown on the first page and the data ends pretty much on the last line of the page.

The second tablix is hidden in this particular scenario but since I have left about 1cm gap between tablixes, this causes a new empty page to be created. Is there any way of removing this gap?

Answer (score 0):

Move the tablix's closer together (basically remove as much whitespace as you can)

If you need more space when you are showing the tablix - add a row to the top of the tablix and set its visibility to false.

This is often caused by the *feature* of ssrs preserving whitespace around objects that are hidden

Answer (score 0):

Check for the page breaks in the tablix properties. It may be there which is causing this.

Comment: My issue doesn't always happen. There's definitely no page breaks and I've also checked that the body+left margin+right margin <= page width